# How to link nav buttons

Tags: html, css

I'm running through a tutorial on YouTube on how to build a website. It was good info, but the person didn't mention how to make menu buttons work. For example, I have About Me, Favorite Quotes, Portfolio, and Contact Me. My index.html serves as my About Me. I assumed that to make something like Favorite Quotes work, I would need to copy/paste index.html into quotes.html and then it'd be clickable, but it doesn't work. Looking at the nav tags, I assume that I need to use the class="current" command, but every tutorial I've seen them implemented in have used lists. The nav tags in my code don't use lists so I am unsure how to link my html page menus together.

How do I make something like Favorite Quotes be clickable and not send me to the "this webpage is not found" error? I know I have to utilize class="current", but I am not sure how to incorporate it in a non-list environment. I understand that I need to make a separate html file for each menu item, but I am not sure what to put in those files to make them work. To clarify, everything is clickable, but I am not sure how to use the buttons to send me to a new page. For example, if I click on Portfolio, it should use my portfolio.html to send me to that page, but I am not sure how to do this. I suspect that the problem lies in the way I'm handling the nav tags.

Here is my code for index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Website!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/screen_styles.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/screen_layout_large.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:50px) and (max-width:500px)"
              href="css/screen_layout_small.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:501px) and (max-width:800px)"
              href="css/screen_layout_medium.css" />
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="page">

            <header>

                <a class="logo" href="#"></a>

            </header>

            <article>

                <h1>Welcome!</h1>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit sed do eiusmod tempor 
                   incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis 
                   nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
                   <a href="#">Duis aute irure</a> dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse c
                   illum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non 
                   proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>


            </article>

            <div class="promo_container">

                <div class="promo one">

                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>Promo Heading Here</h3>
                        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum 
                           dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.</p>
                        <p><a class="cta" href="">Visit our blog</a></p>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="promo two">

                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>Promo Heading Here</h3>
                        <p>Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
                           deserunt mollit est laborum.</p>
                        <p><a class="cta" href="">Read the article</a></p>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <div class="promo three">

                    <div class="content">
                        <h3>Promo Heading Here</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit sed do eiusmod tempor 
                           inci did unt.</p>
                        <p><a class="cta" href="">Learn more</a></p>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="clear-fix"></div>

            </div>

            <nav>

                <a href="index.html">About Me</a>
                <a href="quote.html">Favorite Quotes</a>
                <a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a>
                <a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a>

            </nav>

            <footer>

                &copy; Your Organization Name

            </footer>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my screen_layout_large.css

```
@charset "UTF-8";

/* Layout (global rules for all sizes) */

body {margin: 0; padding: 0;}

header a.logo {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

nav{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #a6430a;
}

/* Layout Large Screens (default for older browsers) */

header {
    height: 275px;
    background: url(../images/banner_large.jpg) no-repeat right 0px;
}

header a.logo {
    width: 150px;
    height: 85px;
    top: 28px;
    right: 30px;
    background-image: url(../images/logo_large.png);
}

article{padding: 60px 20px 10px 20px;}

.promo_container {padding: 0px 0px 15px 20px;}
.promo_container .promo {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
    background-position: 0px 3px;
}
.promo_container .promo .content {padding: 0px 30px 0px 70px;}

nav {top: 275px;}
nav a {margin: 12px 0px 10px 20px;}

@media screen and (max-width: 990px){
    footer {padding-left: 20px;}
}
```

Here is my screen_layout_medium.css

```
@charset "UTF-8";

/* Layout Medium Screens */

header {height: 200px; background: url(../images/banner_medium.jpg) no-repeat 90% 0px;}
header a.logo {
    width: 115px;
    height: 70px;
    top: 20px; right: 20px;
    background-image: url(../images/logo_medium.png);
}

nav {top: 200px;}
nav a {margin-right: 20px;}

.promo_container {padding: 0px 20px 15px 20px;}

.promo_container .promo {background-position: 0px 0px;}

.promo_container .promo .content {padding: 70px 30px 0px 0px;}

body {background-image: none;}
```

Here is my screen_layout_small.css

```
@charset "UTF-8";

/* Layout Small Screens */

header {height: 75px; background: url(../images/banner_small.jpg) no-repeat right 0px;}

header a.logo {
    width: 105px;
    height: 40px;
    top: 16px;
    right: 15px;
    background-image: url(../images/logo_small.png);
}

article {padding: 20px 20px 10px 20px;}

nav {
    position: static;
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
    background-color: #515673;
}

nav a {
    color: #a6abc5;
    display: block;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 9px;
    border: 1px solid #a6abc5;
    background: url (../images/mobile_link_arrow.png) no-repeat right center;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
nav a:hover {color: #fff; background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.15);}

.promo_container {padding: 0px;}

.promo_container .promo {
    width: auto;
    float: none;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
    background-position: 20px 13px;
    border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.promo_container .promo .content {padding: 0px 20px 5px 90px;}

footer {border-top: 1px solid #a6abc5;}

body {background-image: none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

the `anchor` tags (`<a>`) are the elements that direct a web page from one page to another. Your anchor tags look like `<a class="logo" href="#">...</a>` but what they should look like is: `<a class="logo" href="index.html">...</a>`.

Each page must correctly indicate which file each `<a>` tag will redirect to.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. When I click on my logo, it shouldn't take me anywhere so that's why I left it as a #. I am talking specifically about when I click on menu items. I believe my problem lies in the way I've written the nav tags. I have 4 buttons: ABOUT ME, FAVORITE QUOTES, PORTFOLIO, and CONTACT ME. They're all clickable, but I'm not sure how to make them take me to the html files for quotes, portfolio, or contact. My index.html is my ABOUT ME AKA home page so that one works. My main problem is I'm not sure how to link the other 3 pages or even what to put in them.

Comment: In other words, am I copy/pasting index.html into quotes.html, portfolio.html, and contact.html while making text changes? If so, this is what I've done, but I am not sure how to make my site transition from page to page. Hopefully, my question makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

first you have to know about links that how it works i will give u an example like you want to open google.com what might be the syntax

```
<a class="logo" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

in the above code the `class` specify the CSS styles that has to be applied on this link, the `href` is the actual link on which it should be directed and the inside the tags `Google` will be shown on the web page when u click on it, the google will open if u really need to know about web development i will suggest u [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Are your other pages in the same directory as your 'index.html'? the anchor tags () with the href attribute is what makes a link work. But if you don't specify the correct path in the href it wont be able to find the file your trying to redirect to. Also if your new to web design I would suggest going through the tutorials on W3Schools at http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp and the tutorials on CodeAcademy at https://www.codecademy.com

There will be some overlapping content between the two set of tutorials but they will give you a solid base to start with.

Answer (score 0):

All links are `<a></a>` tags. If you are trying to link two pages that are in the same directory, simply add the name of the file to the `href` attribute. Like this:

```
<a href="quotes.html">Favorite Quotes</a>
```

Notice that you wrap `<a></a>` tags around elements that you would like to be clicked. e.g.(An image, a line of text, etc.) The type of link shown above uses what is called a "Relative Path". This means you aren't using the full web domain and directory in the href attribute. This is the simplest way to link pages, especially those in the same directory.